# RxJava - Zip operator - handle network error (skip)

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I need to have sequential calls, for fetching network data, but I am struggling with error handling.

I am doing parallel requests using `Single.zip` operator.
One request returns `Single<ResponseOne>` and the second one `Single<List<ResponseTwo>>`, but I want to skip/ignore any errors which may occur while requesting for any of those network calls (for example, status code 500).

Also, I don't want to return default values or objects, I just want the request which failed to be completely ignored.

> How can I zip these two requests and skip errors? Any simple example?

Comment: What is happening now ? Just skip the on error part

Comment: With zip operator, if something fails, everything fails.

Comment: What do u mean by fail ? Network error like some error `statusCode = 500` or something ? What exactly do u mean by fail ?

Comment: Added on description. Yes, for example, status code 500.

Comment: So u want the other response even if one response fails ?

Comment: @SantanuSur right.

Comment: In case `statusCode = 500` , if you have the `statusCode` `field` directly inside the POJO class . It should **not fail** . The on next method will be triggered with one response having just the `statusCode = 500` and the other response with **full** data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested the below code but you probably wouldn't want to use a zip ideally because that has to have equal amount of responses from all upstream subscriptions (Have 3 Single's Zipped then all 3 need to emit 1 event to get a response)

Generally it's better to have a state object and use `scanWith`.

That said one way is to use an `Optional` style object, combined with `onErrorReturnItem`

e.g:

```
data class CombinedResult(
  val responseOne: ResponseOne? = null,
  val responseTwo: List<ResponseTwo>? = null
)
```

```
val firstSingle: Single<Optional<RequestOne>> = requestOne.onErrorReturnItem(Optional.empty())
val secondSingle: Single<Optional<Request = requestTwo.onErrorReturnItem(Optional.empty())

Single.zip(fistSingle, secondSingle, BiFunction { r1: Optional<RequestOne>, r2: Optional<List<RequestTwo>> ->
  return@BiFunction CombinedResult(r1.value, r2.value)
})
```

You can create your own optional if your not sure what that should look like:

```
class Optional<T>(val value: T?) {
  companion object {
    fun <T> empty() = Optional<T>()
    fun <T> from(value: T?) = Optional(value)
  }
}
```

I took this Java `Optional` class from Guava, but Guava is huge so I would only use that unless it's in your project already.

```
@GwtCompatible(serializable = true)
public abstract class Optional<T> implements Serializable {
  /**
   * Returns an {@code Optional} instance with no contained reference.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method is equivalent to Java 8's
   * {@code Optional.empty}.
   */
  public static <T> Optional<T> absent() {
    return Absent.withType();
  }

  /**
   * Returns an {@code Optional} instance containing the given non-null reference. To have {@code
   * null} treated as {@link #absent}, use {@link #fromNullable} instead.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> no differences.
   *
   * @throws NullPointerException if {@code reference} is null
   */
  public static <T> Optional<T> of(T reference) {
    return new Present<T>(checkNotNull(reference));
  }

  /**
   * If {@code nullableReference} is non-null, returns an {@code Optional} instance containing that
   * reference; otherwise returns {@link Optional#absent}.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method is equivalent to Java 8's
   * {@code Optional.ofNullable}.
   */
  public static <T> Optional<T> fromNullable(@NullableDecl T nullableReference) {
    return (nullableReference == null) ? Optional.<T>absent() : new Present<T>(nullableReference);
  }

  Optional() {}

  /**
   * Returns {@code true} if this holder contains a (non-null) instance.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> no differences.
   */
  public abstract boolean isPresent();

  /**
   * Returns the contained instance, which must be present. If the instance might be absent, use
   * {@link #or(Object)} or {@link #orNull} instead.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> when the value is absent, this method
   * throws {@link IllegalStateException}, whereas the Java 8 counterpart throws {@link
   * java.util.NoSuchElementException NoSuchElementException}.
   *
   * @throws IllegalStateException if the instance is absent ({@link #isPresent} returns {@code
   *     false}); depending on this <i>specific</i> exception type (over the more general {@link
   *     RuntimeException}) is discouraged
   */
  public abstract T get();

  /**
   * Returns the contained instance if it is present; {@code defaultValue} otherwise. If no default
   * value should be required because the instance is known to be present, use {@link #get()}
   * instead. For a default value of {@code null}, use {@link #orNull}.
   *
   * <p>Note about generics: The signature {@code public T or(T defaultValue)} is overly
   * restrictive. However, the ideal signature, {@code public <S super T> S or(S)}, is not legal
   * Java. As a result, some sensible operations involving subtypes are compile errors:
   *
   * <pre>{@code
   * Optional<Integer> optionalInt = getSomeOptionalInt();
   * Number value = optionalInt.or(0.5); // error
   *
   * FluentIterable<? extends Number> numbers = getSomeNumbers();
   * Optional<? extends Number> first = numbers.first();
   * Number value = first.or(0.5); // error
   * }</pre>
   *
   * <p>As a workaround, it is always safe to cast an {@code Optional<? extends T>} to {@code
   * Optional<T>}. Casting either of the above example {@code Optional} instances to {@code
   * Optional<Number>} (where {@code Number} is the desired output type) solves the problem:
   *
   * <pre>{@code
   * Optional<Number> optionalInt = (Optional) getSomeOptionalInt();
   * Number value = optionalInt.or(0.5); // fine
   *
   * FluentIterable<? extends Number> numbers = getSomeNumbers();
   * Optional<Number> first = (Optional) numbers.first();
   * Number value = first.or(0.5); // fine
   * }</pre>
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method is similar to Java 8's {@code
   * Optional.orElse}, but will not accept {@code null} as a {@code defaultValue} ({@link #orNull}
   * must be used instead). As a result, the value returned by this method is guaranteed non-null,
   * which is not the case for the {@code java.util} equivalent.
   */
  public abstract T or(T defaultValue);

  /**
   * Returns this {@code Optional} if it has a value present; {@code secondChoice} otherwise.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method has no equivalent in Java 8's
   * {@code Optional} class; write {@code thisOptional.isPresent() ? thisOptional : secondChoice}
   * instead.
   */
  public abstract Optional<T> or(Optional<? extends T> secondChoice);

  /**
   * Returns the contained instance if it is present; {@code supplier.get()} otherwise.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method is similar to Java 8's {@code
   * Optional.orElseGet}, except when {@code supplier} returns {@code null}. In this case this
   * method throws an exception, whereas the Java 8 method returns the {@code null} to the caller.
   *
   * @throws NullPointerException if this optional's value is absent and the supplier returns {@code
   *     null}
   */
  @Beta
  public abstract T or(Supplier<? extends T> supplier);

  /**
   * Returns the contained instance if it is present; {@code null} otherwise. If the instance is
   * known to be present, use {@link #get()} instead.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method is equivalent to Java 8's
   * {@code Optional.orElse(null)}.
   */
  @NullableDecl
  public abstract T orNull();

  /**
   * Returns an immutable singleton {@link Set} whose only element is the contained instance if it
   * is present; an empty immutable {@link Set} otherwise.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method has no equivalent in Java 8's
   * {@code Optional} class. However, this common usage:
   *
   * <pre>{@code
   * for (Foo foo : possibleFoo.asSet()) {
   *   doSomethingWith(foo);
   * }
   * }</pre>
   *
   * ... can be replaced with:
   *
   * <pre>{@code
   * possibleFoo.ifPresent(foo -> doSomethingWith(foo));
   * }</pre>
   *
   * @since 11.0
   */
  public abstract Set<T> asSet();

  /**
   * If the instance is present, it is transformed with the given {@link Function}; otherwise,
   * {@link Optional#absent} is returned.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method is similar to Java 8's {@code
   * Optional.map}, except when {@code function} returns {@code null}. In this case this method
   * throws an exception, whereas the Java 8 method returns {@code Optional.absent()}.
   *
   * @throws NullPointerException if the function returns {@code null}
   * @since 12.0
   */
  public abstract <V> Optional<V> transform(Function<? super T, V> function);

  /**
   * Returns {@code true} if {@code object} is an {@code Optional} instance, and either the
   * contained references are {@linkplain Object#equals equal} to each other or both are absent.
   * Note that {@code Optional} instances of differing parameterized types can be equal.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> no differences.
   */
  @Override
  public abstract boolean equals(@NullableDecl Object object);

  /**
   * Returns a hash code for this instance.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this class leaves the specific choice of
   * hash code unspecified, unlike the Java 8 equivalent.
   */
  @Override
  public abstract int hashCode();

  /**
   * Returns a string representation for this instance.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this class leaves the specific string
   * representation unspecified, unlike the Java 8 equivalent.
   */
  @Override
  public abstract String toString();

  /**
   * Returns the value of each present instance from the supplied {@code optionals}, in order,
   * skipping over occurrences of {@link Optional#absent}. Iterators are unmodifiable and are
   * evaluated lazily.
   *
   * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method has no equivalent in Java 8's
   * {@code Optional} class; use {@code
   * optionals.stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)} instead.
   *
   * @since 11.0 (generics widened in 13.0)
   */
  @Beta
  public static <T> Iterable<T> presentInstances(
      final Iterable<? extends Optional<? extends T>> optionals) {
    checkNotNull(optionals);
    return new Iterable<T>() {
      @Override
      public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new AbstractIterator<T>() {
          private final Iterator<? extends Optional<? extends T>> iterator =
              checkNotNull(optionals.iterator());

          @Override
          protected T computeNext() {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              Optional<? extends T> optional = iterator.next();
              if (optional.isPresent()) {
                return optional.get();
              }
            }
            return endOfData();
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
}
```

Comment: It makes sense. Will try it. Could add the Optional class as Java?. Thanks

Comment: Added the one from Guava.